# How can I launch Image Asset Studio (Android SDK commandline tools) from the command line?

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-asset-studio

I am trying to run [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) from the Android SDK and am encountering an error I cannot solve.

To give a little bit of background, I am presently limited by an ageing laptop (AMD A4-5000, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB hybrid disk [256 MB? SSD]) and, whilst I don't really have any major issue with Android Studio IDE, I find it very bloated and eats up my CPU time and memory. Visual Studio Code on the other hand, suits my cross-platform developing needs almost perfectly, is lightweight and with a plethora of extensions covering all I have needed thus far.

I am attempting to simply execute the Image Asset Studio *.jar* file from the command line and am encountering a *Class Not Found* error that suggests my paths might not be configured correctly, but as far as I can tell, all is well... all the other tools I have used have all worked as expected, but this is the first time I have tried to use one of the JAR applets from the /lib/ directory.

I have the latest (AFAIK) Android SDK command-line tools installed in my home directory, and I am trying to launch the Image Asset Studio from the command line. Two examples I have tried are:

> ~/android/tools/lib$  **java asset-studio-26.0.0-dev.jar**
>
> ~/$  **java ./android/tools/lib/asset-studio-26.0.0-dev.jar**

These give me the following error, or variations thereof:

> Error: Could not find or load main class android.tools.lib.asset-studio-26.0.0-dev.jar
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class asset-studio-26.0.0-dev.jar

Also, I have tried with the *-jar* flag:

> ~$  **java -jar ~/android/tools/lib/asset-studio-26.0.0-dev.jar**
>
> no main manifest attribute, in /home/noscere/android/tools/lib/asset-studio-26.0.0-dev.jar

Different error, same effect :-)

I was previously getting a different error, which related to the wrong Java [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment) being executed (I have 11 installed as well as the required 8 - solved with a quick `sudo update-alternatives --config java`). Here is my current Java version:

> ~/android$ **java -version**
>
> **openjdk version "1.8.0_342"**
> **OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_342-8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)**
>
> **OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.342-b07, mixed mode)**

For reference, **sdkmanager --version** gives an output of **7.0** - if that helps identify my SDK version.

Is it possible to be successful in running any of the SDK Java apps from outside of the Studio IDE? All the other command line tools (sdkmanager, avdmanager, adb, etc.) are all working seamlessly thus far. In fact, I've not encountered any issue with my Visual Studio Code + SDK command-line tools development environment (well, that hasn't quick-fixable), until now...

My environment variables relating to the Android SDK are as follows (and all correct):

> **export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android**
>
> **export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$PATH**
>
> **export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH**
>
> **export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH**
>
> **export REPO_OS_OVERRIDE="Linux"**

I'm stumped. Google-searching has thus far been fruitless. I'm loathe to install Android Studio IDE just for this, when I have successfully developed several apps over the years without needing it. I'm loathe to admit defeat.

Comment: "All the other command line tools (sdkmanager, avdmanager, adb, etc) are all working seamlessly thus far" -- the Image Asset wizard is not a command-line tool. It is part of Android Studio. "I'm loathe to install Android Studio IDE just for this" -- have you considered using online equivalents? `android icon builder` in search engines turns up lots of options, such as https://appicon.co/.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's amazing how many things you've never noticed before no matter how (in)experienced one may be. Thanks for the quick reply. I shall try more searches with some different terms. I don't like relying on online tools when the functionality should work offline... but if it saves banging my head on the monitor, so be it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IconKitchen](https://icon.kitchen) which is online and works great.